# Async Await or TPL

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am updating a C# WPF .NET 4.0 application, which is using `BackroundWorker` in order to keep the UI responsive.  Should I upgrade it to .NET 4.5 to get async await features or keep .NET 4 and use the TPL. The app is going to be updated frequently and all relative components are availible in .NET 4.5.

Comment: That is kind of up to you to be honest.  I personally love the new async and await features and use it for all server programming that requires asynchronous.  Once all of our client machines have been upgraded to windows 7, I will be using it for all client apps as well.

Comment: The app is going to be used in win7 and above environment

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd look at the features and improvements .NET 4.5 offers you over those of .NET 4.

It is a choice nobody else here can really make for you, as you're the one developing the application. Personally, I'd probably go with .NET 4.5, but depending on your environment/constraints etc. you may be better off sticking with .NET 4 and using the TPL instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already updating the app, I'd recommend moving to `async`/`await`.

You can either upgrade the project to use .NET 4.5 (which I recommend unless you need to support Windows XP), or you can keep it on .NET 4.0 and use the NuGet package `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` (which I recommend only if you need XP support).

Comment: Actually the app will be running in win7 and above.... the only reluctance I have is that I need to force the client to install net4.5